# how to pop a dialog in mobile using mobile jquery with out click event

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have tried some of the snippets but some how it does not work for me may be my approach is not correct.

it just displays dialog wihout poping

here is my completed code. 
Some body please help me out.

i tried this code in jsbin.com editer.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css"     rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"   src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>  

 </head>
 <body>

 <div id="divid" data-rel="dialog" > 
 dialog
 </div>


</div>


<script>

(function(){

  $.mobile.changePage( $('#divid'), { role: 'dialog', transition: 'pop'} );


})();

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Note:** The dialog widget is deprecated in **1.4** and will be removed in **1.5**. The page widget now has the dialog option which, when set to true will apply dialog styling to a page.

As of jQuery Mobile, there is no `data-role=dialog`, instead, a page can be converted into a dialog by add `data-dialog="true"` attribute to *page* div.

```
<div data-role="page" data-dialog="true" id="foo">
  <div data-role="header" data-close-btn="right">
     <h1>Dialog</h1>
  </div>
  <!-- contents -->
</div>
```

To call it programmatically:

```
$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "#foo", {
    transition: "pop"
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/2X63p/)**

Comment: how do i close the dialog, if user taps anywhere on the dialog ?

Comment: @vinay use `$("#dialogID").dialog("close");`.